# Is it possible to get launcher font, font size and font color?

Tags: android, widget

I have widget with some sign below it.
Standart font is different from launcher font see screenshot:

[image]

Is it possible to get font used on launcher and make my sign with the same font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Homescreen is the regular Android application, developed by android programmers like you. It is not a part of the system, since anyone can develop his own launcher application (Homescreen as you call it). You can see that there are hundreds of launcher applications in google play currently.